# Appium failed to respond after opening the native iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, appium, appium-ios, appium-desktop

We are experiencing difficulties while running Appium script for native iOS app. It opens the app, then it stand still and does not respond to scripts. Please refer to below Logs which we got through terminal. We have also activated XcodeLogs through Capabilities.

```
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] 2018-10-30 19:50:16.262904+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-

Runner[1899:251246] Enqueue Failure: Failure fetching attributes for 
(null): 
Error Domain=com.apple.XCTestErrorDomain Code=1000 "Timeout waiting for fulfillment of promise for 'Fetching attributes for (null)'." UserInfo=

{NSLocalizedDescription=Timeout waiting for fulfillment of promise for 'Fetching attributes for (null)'.} 

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgentRunner/UITestingUITests.m 37 1
[Xcode] 


[Xcode] 2018-10-30 19:50:16.265961+0530 WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner[1899:251246] Enqueue Failure: Failure getting list of active applications: (null) 

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/WebDriverAgentRunner/UITestingUITests.m 37 1


[Xcode] 
[Xcode] t = 322.45s Unable to monitor event loop
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] t = 322.47s Unable to monitor animations
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] t = 322.48s Open com.release.demoapp
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] t = 322.48s Launch com.release.demoapp
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] t = 322.48s Terminate com.release.demoapp:1904
[Xcode] 
[Xcode] t = 323.72s Wait for com.release.demoapp to idle
[Xcode]


[debug] 

[XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session (An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT). Retrying...


[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionAttempted' logged at 1540909218924 (19:50:18 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))


[debug] [XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Matched '/session' to command name 'createSession'
[debug] [JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /session] to [POST 

http://localhost:52148/session] with body: {"desiredCapabilities":{"bundleId":"com.release.demoapp","arguments":[],"environment":{},"shouldWaitForQuiescence":true,"shouldUseTestManagerForVisibilityDetection":true,"maxTypingFrequency":10,"shouldUseSingletonTestManager":false}}
```

Capabilities:

```
{
"android": {
"platformName": "android",
"platformVersion": "8.0",
"app": "./build/Sapphire.apk",
"appPackage": "com.release.muvisdk",
"appActivity": "com.home.vod.activity.SplashScreen",
"deviceName": "android",
"noSign": true,
"avdLaunchTimeout":300000,
"avdReadyTimeout":300000,
"autoGrantPermissions": true
},
"iOS": {
"platformName": "iOS",
"app": {
"device" : "./build/Sapphire.app",
"simulator": "./build/SapphireSim.app"
},
"deviceName": "iPhone",
"wdaLaunchTimeout": 80000,
"wdaConnectionTimeout": 80000,
"preventWDAAttachments": true,
"clearSystemFiles": true,
"shouldUseSingletonTestManager": false,
"simpleIsVisibleCheck": true,
"maxTypingFrequency": 10,
"showXcodeLog": true,
"autoAcceptAlerts": true,
"useNewWDA": true,
"fullReset": true,
"newCommandTimeout": 60,
"showIOSLog": true
},
"hostMachines": 
[
{
"machineIP": "127.0.0.1",
"simulators": 
[
]
}
],
"ATDServiceHost":"127.0.0.1",
"ATDServicePort":"3000"
}
```

Comment: Share the version of Appium server and Java client used along with capabilities. Also the version of XCode and iOS in question.

Comment: Thank you for helping. Below are all details

appium - 1.9.1, xcode - 10, ios - 12.0, mac os 10.14
appium - 1.9.1, xcode - 10, ios - 12.0, mac os 10.13.6
appium - 1.9.2beta2, xcode - 10, ios - 12.0, mac os 10.13.6

Comment: Also share the capabilities used.

Comment: @WasiqBhamla, I added the capabilities in Question itself.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I have the same error